# elem.click is not happening in angular unit test?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Wrote a simple directive with a click event. It looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('myDirective',
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<span ng-click="klik();">{{value}}</span>',
      controller:function($scope)
      {
        $scope.klik= function()
        {
          $scope.value='you clicked on it!!';
        }
      }
    }
  }
);
```

I can't trigger the click event, why? This is the unit test:

```
describe('testing directive', function (){
  var scope, html, elem, compiled;

  beforeEach(function (){
    module('plunker');

    html = '<my-directive></my-directive>';

    inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
      //create the scope.
      scope = $rootScope.$new();

      //get the element.
      elem = angular.element(html);

      //compile the view.
      compiled = $compile(elem);

      //run the view against the scope.
      compiled(scope);

      //call digest to update the view!
      scope.$digest();
    });
  });

  it('should set text to "you clicked on it!"', function (){
    elem.click();
    expect(elem.value).toBe('you clicked on this!');
  });


})
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError: elem.click is not a function
```

plunkr ref:http://plnkr.co/edit/e4Iood6Xm1qltOtIjo3Z?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You made a few errors in your plunkr. [I fixed them here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/OZnkbaP34p0IJBLRKLbe?p=streamer)

Here's what I did:

1. Changed span to button in the template (don't *need* to do this, but you usually click on buttons).
2. Make sure the test clicks on the *button*, not the directive.
3. Extract the first element of the jquery-wrapped response to the `find` method
4. Call click on the button
5. Change the expected text.

Works for me now.

Comment: great but the plunkr link you posted is the old one?

Comment: Oops. Try this: http://plnkr.co/edit/OZnkbaP34p0IJBLRKLbe?p=streamer  Also, fixed the answer.